# Laravel validation if condition

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate my field. If is_teacher is false and teacher_id is empty. then i will throw error message. But I am not sure why even if the is_teacher field is true they also prompt this error message. Suppose is_teacher is true, then no need enter this condition.

```
if(is_bool($input['is_teacher']) == false && empty($input['teacher_id'])) {
   $validator->errors()->add('teacher_id', 'Please select a teacher.');
   return response()->json([
      'error'    => true,
      'messages' => $validator->errors(),
   ], 422);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_bool`  check whether variable is boolean or not.Variable must be `true` or `false`
for example

```
$input=['is_teacher'=>true];

dd(is_bool($input['is_teacher']));
```

this will return true ;

```
$input=['is_teacher'=>12];

    dd(is_bool($input['is_teacher']));
```

this will return false.

If you see below function then you can see what exactly is_bool will do

```
/**
 * Finds out whether a variable is a boolean
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php
 * @param mixed $var <p>
 * The variable being evaluated.
 * </p>
 * @return bool true if var is a boolean,
 * false otherwise.
 * @since 4.0
 * @since 5.0
 */
function is_bool ($var) {}
```

For more info : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php

**Updated**

```
 $input=[
        'is_teacher'=>0,
        'teacher_id'=>""
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'teacher_id' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($input) {
            return !$input['is_teacher'] && empty($input['teacher_id']);
        }),

    ],[
        'teacher_id.required'=>'Please select a teacher.'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'messages' => $validator->errors(),
        ], 422);
    }
```

You can import valdiation and rule like below

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Response will be

```
{
"error": true,
"messages": {
"teacher_id": [
"Please select a teacher."
]
}
}
```

Comment: i understood what you meant. but what is alternative for me to get to that solution? I have tried using !$input['is_clinic'] to have a condition if false

Comment: oaky i can help.may i know what possible data you are sending in $input['is_teacher']

Comment: ```$input['is_teacher']``` is a boolean type.

Comment: ye i got it what are you passing 0 or 1 || true or false ?

Comment: it is true or false

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your conditional down to the following:

```php
// if `is_teacher` is false AND `teacher_id` is empty
if (!$input['is_teacher'] && !$input['teacher_id']) {
    $validator->errors()->add('teacher_id', 'Please select a teacher.');
    return response()->json([
      'error'    => true,
      'messages' => $validator->errors(),
    ], 422);
}
```

Comment: hi it is not working. I try to debug ```!$input['teacher_id']```it is 1 and for ```!input['is_teacher']``` nothing

Comment: @wolfrogers Have a look at a [working example here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/divine-hill-w0rp-bs2wo)